# Can "perl -a" somehow re-join @F using the original whitespace?

Tags: perl, text-processing

My input has a mix of tabs and spaces for readability. I want to modify a field using `perl -a`, then print out the line in its original form. (The data is from `findup`, showing me a count of duplicate files and the space they waste.) Input is:

```
2 * 4096    backup/photos/photo.jpg photos/photo.jpg
2 * 111276032   backup/books/book.pdf book.pdf
```

The output would convert field 3 to kilobytes, like this:

```
2 * 4 KB    backup/photos/photo.jpg photos/photo.jpg
2 * 108668 KB   backup/books/book.pdf book.pdf
```

In my dream world, this would be my code, since I could just will perl to automatically recombine `@F` and preserve the original whitespace:

```
perl -lanE '$F[2]=int($F[2]/1024)." KB"; print;'
```

In real life, joining with a single space seems like my only option:

```
perl -lanE '$F[2]=int($F[2]/1024)." KB"; print join(" ", @F);'
```

Is there any automatic variable which remembers the delimiters? If I had a magic array like that, the code would be:

```
perl -lanE 'BEGIN{use List::Util "reduce";} $F[2]=int($F[2]/1024)." KB"; print reduce { $a . shift(@magic) . $b } @F;'
```

Comment: Btw, to print with a space between elements: `print "@F";`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, there is no such magic object.  You can do it by hand though

```
perl -wnE'@p = split /(\s+)/; $p[4] = int($p[4]/1024); print @p' input.txt
```

The capturing parens in `split`'s pattern mean that it is also returned, so you catch exact spaces. Since spaces are in the array we now need the fifth field.

As it turns out, `-F` has this same property. Thanks to [Сухой27](https://stackoverflow.com/users/223226/%D0%A1%D1%83%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B927). Then

```
perl -F'(\s+)' -lanE'$F[4] = int($F[4]/1024); say @F' input.txt
```

Note: [with 5.20.0](http://perldoc.perl.org/perl5200delta.html#*-F*-now-implies-*-a*-and-*-a*-implies-*-n*) "*`-F` now implies `-a` and `-a` implies `-n`*". Thanks to [ysth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17389/ysth).

Comment: `-F'(\s+)'` can be used as parameter, and `say` will give extra newline.

Comment: @Сухой27 Wow.  Thank you.  I thought of that and "recalled" that one can only use literals in there.  (I think that "recollection" came from `$/` ...?) Fixed, and added.

Comment: @piojo Updated the answer -- it turns out that there is exactly what you ask.  Also fixed an error.

Comment: Thanks, knowing about `-F<group>` and `split(/<group>/)` will be really useful!

Comment: http://perldoc.perl.org/perl5200delta.html#%2A-F%2A-now-implies-%2A-a%2a-and-%2A-a%2A-implies-%2A-n%2A

Comment: @ysth  Thank you, added.

Answer (score 1):

You could just find the correct part of the line and modify it:

```
perl -wpE's/^\s*+(?>\S+\s+){2}\K(\S+)/int($1\/1024) . " KB"/e'
```

Comment: Escaping `\ ` in code is oh so weird, and avoidable using an alternate delimiter (e.g. `s!...!...!e` or `s{...}{...}e`)